# (Swift 3) I need to send a notification to the user to open the app at a specific time. Better to use a local or push notification?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, ios10

I have 2 options here that I've found, the LocalNotification, or the UNMutableNotification (through the UserNotifications). Which of the 2 would suit my need of sending a notification every day at some set time? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working with iOS 10+, you should schedule your notifications using a [UNNotificationRequest](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationrequest), using a [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/untimeintervalnotificationtrigger) to set the fire dates

Per the Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilocalnotification), `UILocalNotification` was deprecated in iOS 10